# `step` with index

Tags: ruby, iteration

If I have this code:

```
46.step(127, 1) do |i|
end
```

can I get, at the 10th iteration, both `i = 55` and `index = 10` without any external counters?

Comment: Yes. `index = i - 45`.

Comment: You are rejecting answers that express the idiomatic Ruby way to do this, and they meet the requirements in the question ("without any external counters").  Can you please explain why?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the asker doesn't specify all of his requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about the performance implications here, but you could do something like this:

```
46.step(127, 1).each_with_index do |i, index|
end
```

Only, in the 10th iteration `index` would be 9.

Comment: Uhm no. I want to use only step, not .each_with_index. Thanks anyway

Comment: As shown by @sawa's answer (deleted, sadly), #each_with_index can take an offset.  `...each_with_index(1) do...` would cause `index` to be 10 on the 10th iteration.

Comment: @markzzz ... why? Is subtraction disallowed as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should solve your problem.

```
return_array = []
46.step(127, 1) do |i|
    group_array = []
    group_array << i
    return_array << group_array 
    group_array << return_array.find_index(group_array) + 1
end
return_array
```

This will return [ [46, 1], [47, 2], [48, 3], [49, 4], [50, 5], [51, 6], [52, 7], [53, 8], [54, 9], [55, 10], [56, 11], [57, 12], ... , [127, 82] ]